# PHP Dynamically determine fully qualified class name

Tags: php, namespaces

I've found that by using [`::class`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name), I can get the fully qualified class name of a namespaced class:

```
namespace NameSpace {
    class Foo { }
    echo Foo::class;
}
// echoes 'NameSpace\Foo'
```

But I can't figure out a way to do this with a variable class name. Trying to treat the `class` keyword like a static property doesn't seem to work:

```
namespace NameSpace {
    class Foo { }
    $className = 'Foo';
    echo $className::class;
}
// Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class'
```

Does anyone know if its possible to get the fully qualified class name dynamically like I'm trying to?

---

I want to be able to do this with classes from outside the current namespace:

```
namespace ReallyLongHardToWriteNameSpace {
    class Foo { }
}
namespace NameSpace {
    use ReallyLongHardToWriteNameSpace\Foo;
    class Bar { }

    echo Foo::class; // echoes 'ReallyLongHardToWriteNameSpace\Foo'
    echo Bar::class; // echoes 'NameSpace\Bar'

    foreach (['Foo', 'Bar'] as $className) {
        echo $className::class; // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with another solution. Even tho this is somewhat different.

```
namespace NameSpace;
class Foo {
    public static function getFullName() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

print Foo::getFullName(); // Prints NameSpace\Foo
```

Just create a abstract class which has getFullName() as method and inherit from it on all classes you want to be able to return full name.

---

Simplest approch (I almost forgot) is the use of get_class()

```
$className = get_class($yourClassObject); // returns NameSpace\Foo
```

---

You can also try using eval() for this.

```
$className = 'NameSpace\Foo::class';
eval('$fullName = ' . $className);
print $fullName; // returns NameSpace\Foo
```

---

Even tho, this might not be exactly what you want, but you should look at the Reflection library. Its very handy to use for such things.

```
// Lets say you have an object of your class
$object = new ReflectionObject($yourObject);
$name = $object->getName(); // will return NameSpace\Foo

// You can also give the class name to it
$class = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$name = $class->getName(); // also returns NameSpace\Foo
```

Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) for more information
There are also classes for methods, properties, etc.

Comment: `get_class` and the `ReflectionClass` both need you to already know the fully qualified classname as their parameter, which defeats the purpose...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) with an instance of that class:

```
<?php
namespace NS {
    class Foo { }
    $className = "\\NS\\Foo";
    echo get_class(new $className);
}
// prints NS\Foo
```

Do note that to create an instance of the class I had to use the FQN in the string, so it might not be useful at all.

Comment: yeah it defeats the purpose to already have the fully qualified class name as the input

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__NAMESPACE__` to get the current namespace, then just prepend that to the string that contains the class name.

```
namespace NS {
    class Foo {
    }
    $className = 'Foo';
    echo __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $className;
}
```

Comment: That would work if I was always trying to get the fully qualified class name of classes in the current namespace, but not with classes from other namespaces (which is what I'm trying to do, I'll update my question)

Comment: Well then it will never work. If you have a class named `Foo` in the namespace `NS1` and another class named `Foo` in the namespace `NS2` then there is no way to tell which is which unless you have an instance of the object -- in which case you can just call `get_class()` on it.

Comment: But in that case you'd get a `Cannot declare class NS2\Foo` error. I'm only talking about classes in the scope of the namespace or that have been imported with `use`.

Comment: Still won't work. The whole point of namespaces is to avoid the collision of same-named classes. If you're given only a class name, it's not possible to determine its fully qualified name unless you can absolutely guarantee that it's only ever defined in one namespace. And if you can do that, then there's no point to using namespaces.

Comment: Hmm, I think we're not on the same page. If I'm in namespace `NS1` and call `use NS2\Bar;`, and then `echo Bar::class;` it'll echo `NS2\Bar`. I just want to be able to do that dynamically.

Comment: You can't do that. If you're in `NS1` and call `use NS2\Bar` then there is no way to know if `Bar` refers to `NS1\Bar` or `NS2\Bar` or `AnythingElse\Bar`.

Comment: Note, you technically could loop over the output of `get_declared_classes()` and look for a match, but that won't work if you're autoloading and you'll never be guaranteed to get the right one. In any case, if you have to do something like that, it's a pretty big code smell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127328/discussion-between-thanksd-and-alex-howansky).